# JQuery dialog restricting access to .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, anchor, jquery-dialog

I have a JQuery dialog box in which I am using JQuery datatable to display some data. In the datatable, I am displaying a Hyperlink with following code

```
<a href="javascript:callFunction()">Download</a>
```

But the call to javascript method is not working through dialog.

Could someone please help me in resolving this issue?

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/wrV2b/1/
Created the Jsfiddle for my issue.

Thanks,
Hareesh

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the JavaScript console? Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @JeromyFrench: http://jsfiddle.net/wrV2b/1/ I have created this fiddle, Please let me know what error I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:callFunction()">Download</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callFunction();">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to consider using a Div or Button rather than using an anchor. E.g:

```
<div onclick="callFunction()">Download</div>
```

or

```
<button onclick="callFunction()">Download</button>
```

A div/button will give you greater control over the appearance without inheriting all the formatting from the browser. IMO it's more intuitive, too: links take you somewhere, buttons do something.